# Send an Intent for the user to select a file on Android

Tags: android, file, android-intent, file-io

Is there a default activity in Android that handles the opening of files? For example in Quickoffice, you can open a file, but it doesn't allow you to navigate directories. This might be an old-school type of request, but in an application I'm developing, I want to send an Intent to request the user to select a file. My application will then process that file.

Ideally, this will end up as a Settings configuration for a service that will be used by other applications.

Edit: I'm browsing the documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html, but in my case, I want to store and retrieve data that doesn't fit in any of the categories:

- Music/ - Media scanner classifies all media found here as user music.
- Podcasts/ - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a podcast.
- Ringtones/ - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a ringtone.
- Alarms/ - Media scanner classifies all media found here as an alarm sound.
- Notifications/ - Media scanner classifies all media found here as a notification sound.
- Pictures/ - All photos (excluding those taken with the camera).
- Movies/ - All movies (excluding those taken with the camcorder).
- Download/ - Miscellaneous downloads.

Comment: The same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042308/select-a-music-file-to-play-with-mediaplayer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a default activity in Android that handles the opening of files?

For the types of files managed by `MediaStore` (e.g., MIME type `audio/*`), `ACTION_PICK` works. For arbitrary files, no.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a library like [android-file-dialog](http://code.google.com/p/android-file-dialog/), or build your own picker.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up making my own picker.