# Is the android emulator able to upload files to a server

Tags: php, android, file-upload, emulation

I cannot find this anywhere.  Is the android emulator able to upload files to a web server?  I have been testing for the last hour or so and just realized it may not even be possible.  Anyone know?

Comment: It is. Check if the emulator is connected to the internet. If so, maybe the problem is in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible.  It's a little complex to post the code but essentially you'd use File class to find which file you want to upload and then use the apache HttpClient library to do the multiform post.  Now if you think it won't work because you don't know what interface the user will use to find the file.  There is a way to send an Intent to open a file.

[Send an Intent for the user to select a file on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322915/send-an-intent-for-the-user-to-select-a-file-on-android)

But the rest is simply writing the code to perform the upload.

Comment: If you are having network issues it can be several things.  1 the emulator doesn't work if you switch the network you are connected to.  Close your laptop, change wifi, etc will cause it to forget stuff.  Fix it by shutting down and restarting the emulator.  2 test your network connection by just using the web browser.  If that will load a web page then the network is working.  If it won't you got some debugging to do.

Comment: alrighty thanks for the info.  I'm using phonegap so the upload isn't too complicated but I suppose that I just have an error somewhere.