# Android - How to create MediaPlayer from a user selected song

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, filechooser

this is the intent which opens a chooser from the music app

```
public void launchMusicPlayer(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i,1);
    }
```

and below is the **onActivityResult** code to try and obtain the song
, but the problem is that the test button when pressed, does not play anything
and as i am new to coding i don't know what i am doing wrong.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1) {
        final MediaPlayer testSong = new MediaPlayer();
        Uri songUri = data.getData();

            try {
                testSong.setDataSource(this, songUri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        testSong.prepareAsync();

        test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                testSong.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue maybe because `prepareAsync()` is asynchronous, so the MediaPlayer may not be ready when you call `start()`. There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Use `prepare()` instead of `prepareAsync()`

   ```
   test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           testSong.prepare(); 
           testSong.start();
       }
   });
   ```
2. call `start()` method inside `setOnPreparedListener()`

   ```
   test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           testSong.prepareAsync(); 
           testSong.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

               @Override
               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
                   player.start();
               }
           }
   });
   ```

Refer to the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried your method however still the same issue. So I made an onClickListener for the button in onCreate of activity to play a specific song from the raw folder and this works. But if I pick a song from the chooser then press the test button it still plays the song from the raw folder meaning it is not even reading the onActivityResult so what should I do? @Tony Vu

Comment: Oh that will be different issue from your original post. Anyway, I think the problem is with the Uri returned by data.getData(). It may need some processing before passing to setDataSource(). You can try the methods as recommended by this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17042308/select-a-music-file-to-play-with-mediaplayer

Comment: Thank you @Tony Vu I got it to work with the last answer within that question